# i cant use RTCVideoRenderer's mirror property.. How resolve this problem?

Tags: api, flutter, mobile, webrtc, videocall

I'm making Videocall application with Flutter,WebRTC.

my IDE is Android studio.

I'm using RTCVideoRenderer.

but I can't use renderVideo property..

I searched about [RTCVideoRenderer](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webrtc/latest/flutter_webrtc/RTCVideoRenderer-class.html) usage.

this link describes renderVideo property that can be used.

But I cant use renderVideo property..

Here is the error message:

```
There isn’t a setter named 'renderVideo' in class 'RTCVideoRenderer'.  Try correcting the name to reference an existing setter, or declare the setter.
```

How to resolve... this problem???

I can use another property..

Answer (score 4):

First you initialize a renderer

```
 final _yourRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
```

and when you want to display it use:

```
RTCVideoView(_yourRenderer, mirror: true,)
```